# Given L1 is regular language and L1△L2 is regular is L2 regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

```
Let L1 and L2 be some languages under some alphabet Σ,
Given that L1 is regular and L1△L2 is regular
prove or disprove L2 must be also regular.
```

Im trying to figure out a counterexample yet couln't find one.

Comment: What is $△$ here? Did you mean intersection $(∩)$ or anything else?

Comment: symmetric difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words in $L2$ are either:

- in $L_1\triangle L_2$ but NOT in $L_1$ (then it originates from $L_2$)
  OR
- NOT in $L_1\triangle L_2$ but in $L_1$ (it is in both $L_1$ and $L_2$)

If both $L_1\triangle L_2$ and $L_1$ are regular, there are finite automata that accept them. For accepting $L_2$ you can run these in parallel and after reading the input word check the two conditions above. Based on that you accept or reject.

Thus $L_2$ is always regular.